# Как в GCC узнать кто ссылается на конкретный символ

Tags: c++, gcc, stm32, ld

Я пишу на Си и С++ под микроконтроллеры STM32. Когда проект слишком разрастается я смотрю какие символы занимают место при помощи команды:

```bash
readelf -s -W build/my-programm.elf | sort -n -k 3,3
```

Но иногда она выдаёт мне символы, которые я совершенно не использую. Но они занимают место и много.

Я вижу два варианта решения данной проблемы:

1. Узнать кто вызывает указанный символ при помощи статического анализатора. Профилировщики не предлагать, поскольку код выполняется на микроконтроллере.
2. Насильно удалить данный символ из результатов компиляции и тогда я узнаю кто его использует по ошибкам во время компоновки.

Если кто знает другое решение данной проблемы, рассмотрю любые варианты.

Comment: ¿Почему бы не воспользоваться поиском в вашей IDE? *"Профилировщики не предлагать, поскольку код выполняется на микроконтроллере."* - ¿Почему бы и нет?

Comment: Можно objdump-ом сделать из .elf дизассемблерный листинг и поискать этот адрес  в любимом редакторе  (в начале листинга будет таблица символов с адресами)

Comment: @user7860670, Я в качестве IDE использую CLion от JetBrains. Если Вы знаете, то скажите как конкретно в ней это сделать. Действие весьма специфическое и я не смог найти ничего похожего. Я даже не уверен, что правильно ищу.

Comment: @avp, идея хорошая, но что мне это даст? Как мне потом узнать какой код на Си использует функцию, которая мне мешает?

Comment: Поиск по символам есть - `Find Usages `

Comment: Нашли вызов, смотрите выше по тексту в какой он функции. Потом идете по прилинкованным библиотекам и с помощью `nm lib.a | grep ...` находите что нужно (это если символ в чужом коде (если в своем, то grep -rn по всем своим сорсам (тогда и дизассемблер не нужен)))

Comment: @user7860670, есть. И он не видит ничего. Совсем.

Comment: ¿А в проект все файлы добавлены? А то с внешними зависимостями clion до сих пор не умеет нормально работать.

Comment: @avp, проблема-то как раз в том, что символ в чужом коде. Конкретно это: _svfprintf_r и _dtoa_r.

Comment: @user7860670, только что ответил для avp, что проблема с библиотечными символами. Пару раз мне удавалось их побороть тотальным выпиливанием всего, что с ними связано. Но по мере роста проекта они снова появляются. И теперь никак не хотят уходить, хотя printf и все его вариации на микроконтроллере мне нафиг не нужны.

Comment: Тогда ищите в дизассемблере, кто их вызывает